# Can not connect to localhost in nodejs with http and express module

Tags: node.js, express, http, localhost, port

I write following in nodejs and run it. but can not connect to localhost:8080. I am use http and express module.

```
const http=require('http');
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 8080;
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.end('Hellow world')
}).listen(PORT);
```

or

```
app.listen(PORT);
app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hellow world");
});
```

Comment: what is your error or problem, cause it worked right.

Comment: It loading. But dont show content.

Answer (score 0):

When I run it on my pc it works fine.

It could be that:

- You are not running it from your pc, so it's not running on localhost.
- The link is not the correct one. The correct one is `http://localhost:8080`
- Try adding `"localhost"` beside PORT to change it to:

```
http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.end('Hellow world')
}).listen(PORT, "localhost");
```

Could you put a picture of the exact error or screen you're seeing?

Comment: It is loading but does not show any content.

Comment: what does the chrome console say